# How can I load content at a specific address (0x63FC4080) in `r0` register using ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

Is there some one line asm instruction, something like `ldr r0, 0x63FC4080`?

Comment: No. You have to load the address to register then load the value pointed to by that address

Comment: You are trying to make ARM into a CISC architecture, which it is not. It is a [RISC-style load/store architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load/store_architecture).

Answer (score 2):

ARM doesn't have an instruction to load an arbitrary 32 bit number. However, you can place the constant somewhere nearby and use a PC-relative load to get the address you want. ARM assemblers typically provide a special notation that generates a *literal pool,* puts your literal in it and then generates an appropriate addressing mode. For example, to do what you want in the GNU assembler for ARM, write

```
ldr r0,=0x63fc4080
```

this assembles to e.g.

```
   0:   e51f0004    ldr r0, [pc, #-4]   ; 4 <.text+0x4>
   4:   63fc4080    .word   0x63fc4080
```

with the location of the literal pool depending on the surrounding code.

Comment: does `ldr r0, =0x63fc4080` places `0x63fc4080` into r0 or the value at that address in r0?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar It places `0x63fc4080` into r0 as you seem to want. If you want the value at that address, do something like `ldr r0, =0x63fc4080` and then `ldr r0,[r0]`.